# Why do I get this error when I try to push my SQLite3 to Postgresql (via Taps) on Cedar Stack?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, taps

I've done quite a bit of research on Heroku Dev Center and I am now looking to the community for help. Here is my problem. I can not push my db to Heroku Cedar Stack. I am trying to migrate a sqlite database to postgresql via Taps gem.  When I am ready to deploy I run:

```
bundle install --without production
heroku run db:push
```

I get the following result:

```
Running db:seed attached to terminal... up, run.17
sh: db:seed: not found
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

And when I run the migration:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I get the following:

```
Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.18
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2367:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
/usr/local/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

Everytime I push to Heroku (git push heroku master) it fails because my gem file is attempting to install sqlite3 gem-even though its inside of the development and test groups in my Gemfile. My database.yml production environment still points to sqlite adapter even after I have run the following command successfully:

```
heroku config:add BUNDLE_WITHOUT="test development" --app app_name_on_heroku
```

Out of ideas. Please help. If its useful I can post results of my gemfile, heroku ps and logs.

Cheers

UPDATE: After following @John's direction I now receive the following terminal message.

```
Sending schema
Schema:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:07
Sending indexes
schema_migrat: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
Sending data
4 tables, 6 records
schema_migrat:   0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--
Saving session to push_201111070749.dat..
!!! Caught Server Exception
HTTP CODE: 500
Taps Server Error: LoadError: no such file to load -- sequel/adapters/
```

And the following warnings:

["/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in `require'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in`block in tsk_require'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:72:in `block in check_requiring_thread'", "<internal:prelude>:10:in`synchronize'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:69:in `check_requiring_thread'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in`tsk_require'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:25:in `adapter_class'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:54:in`connect'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:119:in `connect'", "/app/lib/taps/db_session.rb:14:in`conn'", "/app/lib/taps/server.rb:91:in `block in <class:Server>'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in`call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `block in route'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in`instance_eval'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `route_eval'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:500:in`block (2 levels) in route!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `catch'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in`block in route!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `each'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in`route!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:601:in `dispatch!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in`block in call!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `instance_eval'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in`block in invoke'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `catch'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in`invoke'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `call!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:399:in`call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/auth/basic.rb:25:in `call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in`block in call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1005:in `synchronize'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in`call'", "/home/heroku_rack/lib/static_assets.rb:9:in `call'", "/home/heroku_rack/lib/last_access.rb:15:in`call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:47:in `block in call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in`each'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `call'", "/home/heroku_rack/lib/date_header.rb:14:in`call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:77:in `call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:76:in`block in pre_process'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `catch'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in`pre_process'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in`receive_data'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in`run'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:57:in `start'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/server.rb:156:in`start'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:80:in `start'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in`run_command'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/bin/thin:6:in`'", "/usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'", "/usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in`'"]

Comment: Just as a note which might be helpful to other people: I had the same error as the last one (HTTP CODE: 500 Taps Server Error: LoadError: no such file to load -- sequel/adapters/) and it was because I didn't have any code pushed (it was an empty repository). When I pushed my app, heroku db:push worked.

Comment: Which can easily happen if on the wrong branch - see this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958797/heroku-no-rakefile-found-but-works-locally

Answer (score 2):

Had similar problem. Included SQLite gem in Bundler's development group, and Postgres gem in Production group. Heroku still tries to install SQLite.

Apparently the Cedar stack does't support bundling without certain groups. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler

> Please note - for the time being, the Cedar stack does not support BUNDLE_WITHOUT.

Had to Gemfile.lock, comment out SQLite gem from Gemfile, re-bundle install, add new Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to git and push back up to Heroku. Also, since SQLite is a dependency of Taps I had comment that one out too.

When I want to fire up development environment, its a matter of reversing the above.

Going to just use Postgres in development next time!

Answer (score 1):

First up, the DB push command is

```
heroku db:push
```

not via `heroku run`

I suspect your Sqlite problem (maybe?) down to your syntax for pushing branches - to push a branch to heroku you have to do

```
git push heroku branchname:master
```

Which is saying push my  to the master branch on heroku remote. If you are really doing `git push heroku branchname` you're not actually deploying anything since heroku will only deploy the master branch so you could be making changes in your code, pushing - but actually not affecting the deployed code. Although that doesn't explain why you get a `No rakefile found` message.

Comment: Upvote for the `git push heroku branchname:master` tip. That solved an annoying issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, what actually helps is 2 things

1. Wipe out completely your git repository, then do it from scratch - git init, git add . 
   then git stage . then git commit -m "whatever you want to put here". After that destroy the app, create it again, and do all the steps including db:migrate.
   Make sure you create your app like this: heroku create  --stack cedar
2. Check this link
   https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/ISSUES.md

Comment: Thanks for this. I got so completely frustrated that I just started using Postgresql 9.1 in my dev environment and deploying with pg gem to Cedar and I haven't looked back.

Answer (score 0):

As described in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3#deploy-your-application-to-heroku you just need to deploy your code

```
heroku create
git push heroku master
```