# heroku run rake db:migrate ... rake aborted! No Rakefile found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, abort, rakefile

When I run `heroku run rake db:migrate`, I receive the following error:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.8507
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2367:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
/usr/local/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

Other users have posted identical errors, but in their case they actually didn't have a Rakefile and it worked for them once they created one, or they were in the wrong directory. My app does have a Rakefile, in the correct directory and with all the proper text in it, and I am in my app's root directory.

This is what my Rakefile  looks like:

```
    # Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
    # for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

    require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

    Rails.application.load_tasks
```

This is what "heroku run cat Rakefile" does:

```
    $ heroku run cat Rakefile
    Running `cat Rakefile` attached to terminal... up, run.9132
    cat: Rakefile: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you pushed your rake file on heroku. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958797/heroku-no-rakefile-found-but-works-locally

Comment: You could also try this to ensure that it's not a firewall, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892200/cant-heroku-run-rake-db-migrate-through-my-app

Comment: @user2675613 Yes, pushing it on heroku was the last command I did before trying to migrate.

Comment: @DaneBalia That command has worked before for different apps and I haven't adjusted my firewall since making those apps, so it can't be that.

Comment: What does `heroku run cat Rakefile` look like?

Comment: @Unixmonkey Apparently the same error: I posted the result in the question.

Comment: So the file doesn't exist on Heroku's servers. You say it is in the correct directory, but is it in the root dir? Is it not tracked by Git (you can check with `git ls-files Rakefile --error-unmatch`)?

Comment: @Unixmonkey Yes, it is in the root dir. I ran that command, and got back only "Rakefile". What does that mean?

Comment: @user3739453 that means it is committed. I'm Stumped.

Comment: I am not sure. Try to use following in Rakefile:
    require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
    require 'rake'
    Rails.application.load_tasks

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958797/heroku-no-rakefile-found-but-works-locally. That solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Whenever you are struggling with Heroku you should check your logs:

```
heroku logs
```

Scan through for any errors that you can google and/or get hints to what is going wrong.

#### If you are using git you can quickly search for errors with this:

```
git grep "whatever you want to search for"
```

#### You will then know where to find the file so you might try to verify that the rakefile actually exists with:

```
git grep rakefile
```

#### Sometimes it is easier to just start fresh and reset your database and reload your current schema with:

```
rake db:reset db:migrate all
```

#### This will destroy your db and then create it and then migrate your current schema:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

#### If you want to reset the heroku db

#### To drop the database, if you are using SHARED_DATABASE_URL:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
```

#### To recreate the database with nothing in it:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

#### To populate the database with your seed data:

```
heroku run rake db:seed
```

Comment: I have the same problem and can't figure out how your answer solves it? Most of the commands here are rake commands that cannot be run because of the "No Rakefile" issue.